# Post-processing of full_join output to remove multiplicity

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, merge

I have two data frames(`df1`, `df2`) and performed `full_join` using the common column of interest `col1`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','D','C','C','E','E','I'),col2=c(4,7,8,3,2,4,9))
df2 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','A','B','C','C','E','E','I'),col2=c(4,1,6,8,3,2,1,9))

df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = "col1")
#    col1 col2.x col2.y
# 1     A      4      4
# 2     A      4      1
# 3     D      7     NA
# 4     C      8      8
# 5     C      8      3
# 6     C      3      8
# 7     C      3      3
# 8     E      2      2
# 9     E      2      1
# 10    E      4      2
# 11    E      4      1
# 12    I      9      9
# 13    B     NA      6
```

As expected the `full_join` provides multiplicty of the joining column values and I wish to avoid it. I wish to arrive at the following output. What kind of post-processing approaches do you suggest?

```
#    col1 col2.x col2.y
# 1     A      4      4
# 2     A     NA      1
# 3     D      7     NA
# 4     C      8      8
# 5     C      3      3
# 6     E      2      2
# 7     E      4      1
# 8     I      9      9
# 9     B     NA      6
```

More information:

**Case 1**: I do not need four rows in the output for two same values in both input objects:

```
# 4     C      8      8
# 5     C      8      3
# 6     C      3      8
# 7     C      3      3
```

instead, I want only two as:

```
# 4     C      8      8
# 5     C      3      3
```

**Case 2**: Similarly, I need same row for the difference in values:

```
# 8     E      2      2
# 9     E      2      1
# 10    E      4      2
# 11    E      4      1
```

instead, I want only two rows as below:

```
# 8     E      2      2
# 9     E      4      1
```

Comment: In your first case why do you remove 8,3 and 3, 8 values?

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for your attention. I am not interested in the combination of these values. I am only checking if the complete row(s) exist in the other object or not. So, 8,8 and 3,3 are just fine.If they do not exist, what is the replacement value? If there is no replacement value, then `NA`! It's the same from the other (second) object point-of-view too.

Comment: In your expected output 2nd row becomes `NA` and 1. Is that a typo? I still don't understand the logic of your row selection. Do you want to select rows where `col2.x` and `col2.y` are same? But then why do you select  4,1 in 2nd and last row?

Comment: In `df1` there are 1,2,1,2,1 entires for A,C,D,E,I; 2,1,2,2,1 ENTRIES FOR A,B,C,E,I in `df2`. The output should 2,1,2,1,2,1 entires for A,B,C,D,E,I i.e., the entires in the output should be maximum number for entries present in either of these two objects. Secondly, while matching the values, if there are same values for `col1` in `col2` in two objects, there should be only one. If there is second row in only one object, then the other place should be filled with `NA`. For example, `A` has values {4} & {4,1} in `df1`, `df2`. So, the first row in the output contains {4-A-4}.

Comment: The second row contains {NA-A-1} as there no second value for `A` in `df1`. But in case of `E` there are two values in two values in both objects and so, {4-E-1} after {2-E-2}. Hope, I am clear atleast this time. If you understood the logic, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution in 2 steps using the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)-package:

**0) load package & convert to data.table's**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
```

**1) define helper function**

```
unlistSD <- function(x) {
  l <- length(x)
  ls <- sapply(x, lengths)
  m <- max(ls)
  newSD <- vector(mode = "list", length = l)
  for (i in 1:l) {
    u <- unlist(x[[i]])
    lu <- length(u)
    if (lu < m) {
      u <- c(u, rep(NA_real_, m - lu))
    }
    newSD[[i]] <- u
  }
  return(setNames(as.list(newSD), names(x)))
}
```

**2) merge and apply helper function**

```
merge(df1[, .(col2 = list(col2)), by = col1],
      df2[, .(col2 = list(col2)), by = col1],
      by = "col1", all = TRUE
      )[, unlistSD(.SD), by = col1]
```

which gives the following result:

> ```
>    col1 col2.x col2.y
> 1:    A      4      4
> 2:    A     NA      1
> 3:    C      8      8
> 4:    C      3      3
> 5:    D      7     NA
> 6:    E      2      2
> 7:    E      4      1
> 8:    I      9      9
> 9:    B     NA      6
> ```

---

Another possibiliy with base R:

```
unlistDF <- function(d, groupcols) {
  ds <- split(d[, setdiff(names(d), groupcols)], d[,groupcols])
  ls <- lapply(ds, function(x) max(sapply(x, lengths)))
  dl <- lapply(ds, function(x) lapply(as.list(x), unlist))
  du <- Map(function(x, y) {
    lapply(x, function(i) {
      if(length(i) < y) {
        c(i, rep(NA_real_, y - length(i)))
      } else i
    })
    
  }, x = dl, y = ls)
  ld <- lapply(du, as.data.frame)
  cbind(d[rep(1:nrow(d), ls), groupcols, drop = FALSE],
        do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(ld, make.row.names = FALSE)),
        row.names = NULL)
}
```

Now you can use this function as follows in combination with `merge`:

```
df <- merge(aggregate(col2 ~ col1, df1, as.list),
            aggregate(col2 ~ col1, df2, as.list),
            by = "col1", all = TRUE)
unlistDF(df, "col1")
```